# Unable to set breakpoints to see errors C++ ORDERED LIST

Tags: c++, list

I am having a problem trying to use breakpoints in my code to see what is happening step by step. No matter where I put one in my code, it says it can't reach it (even though the code is running through all the functions I told it to), even if I set a conditional to true that definitely should be true (count == 3 for example).

I am setting up an ordered list that inserts movies as strings with certain details for a college project, it adds the movies in order, and then you should be able to delete a specific title. I have used an ordered list using numbers i got working to set this one up as to why I am getting errors, but I cant see what happening as it wont reach any breakpoints, even if i put one on the constructor before anything else is ran. Can anyone tell me why this is happening or what might be wrong with my code. My list remove() function is just removing the last element, instead of the one I have defined.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class OList
{
private:
    string data[3];
    int count; //First empty slot
public:
    OList();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    void Add(string newVal);
    string Remove(string newVal);
    bool LinearSearch(string searchVal);
    void Display();
};

OList::OList()
{
    count = 0;
}

bool OList::isEmpty()
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool OList::isFull()
{
    if (count == 5)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void OList::Add(string movie)
{
    data[count] = movie;
    int i;
    if (isFull())
        return;

    //Find the insertion point
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++);

    if (i == count)
        data[i] = movie; //Copy in the new value
    else
        //Make a Space
        for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--)
        {
            data[j + 1] = data[j];
        }
    data[i] = movie; //Copy in the new value

    count++;
}

string OList::Remove(string movie)
{
    int i = LinearSearch(movie);
    string temp = movie;

    if (isEmpty())
        return false;
    i++;

    while (i < count - 1)
    {
        data[i] = data[i + 1];
        i++;
    }

    count--;
    return temp;
}

bool OList::LinearSearch(string searchVal)
{
    for (int i = 0; (i < count) || (data[i] > searchVal); i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == searchVal)
            return -1;
    }
    return false;
}

void OList::Display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    OList movies;
    string movie;

    movies.Add(movie = "Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani | 1, 790, 000, 000 | Ayan Mukerji");
    movies.Add(movie = "Dhoom 3 | 2,840,000,000 | Vijay Krishna Acharya");
    movies.Add(movie = "Chennai Express | 2, 275, 000, 000 | Rohit Shetty");

    movies.Display();

    std::cout << "\n";

    movies.Remove(movie = "Chennai Express | 2, 275, 000, 000 | Rohit Shetty");

    movies.Display();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @greedy52 Why do you need brackets?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < count; i++);` what's this supposed to do?

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it in a weird way, where i put std::cout << \n; .... I changed to be ..... std::cout << "\n" << endl; ..... and now it lets me see breakpoints and the code is removing Chennai Express. Also I was setting breakpoints in visual studio by clicking to the left of the line of code I want to look into.

Comment: That loop is finding the point to start removing from, and then copy elements down

Comment: @ESuth That loop is not finding anything; it's just a convoluted way of setting `i = count;`.

Comment: Hmm.. okay I prefer `i = count;`

Comment: @melpomene Your right, I dont understand why that needs to be there either, ran through it with a breakpoint and it doesnt do anything... My tutor told us to put that in that function as well

Comment: The code works but the add function doesnt order them numerically and alphabetically

Comment: Also note that the `movie` variable in `main` is pointless, should consider removing and your Remove function is supposed to return a `string` but `ifEmpty == true` you return false. Compiler should be warning of this. Tutor should have told you to start over IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your `Add` function here, not going to go through whole program. Lets say count is `0`

```
void OList::Add(string movie)
{
   data[count] = movie; //data[0] = movie;
   int i;
   if (isFull())
      return;

   //Find the insertion point
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++); //i = 0

   if (i == count) //if i == 0, which we know it does
      data[i] = movie; //data[0] = movie; AGAIN
   else //never enter this...
      //Make space
      for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--)//never get here
      {
         data[j + 1] = data[j];//nope
      }
   data[i] = movie; //data[0] = movie; just to be sure

   count++;
}
```

It might as well be

```
void OList::Add(string movie)
{
   data[count] = movie;
   if (isFull())
      return;
   count++;
}
```

Comment: But if I wanted them to be in order numerically and alphabetically, how would I need the code to be? I used numbers with this add function before and it works well, but I need the add function to work with letters as well. Currently when I add its not ordering them, its listing them out one by one

Comment: @ESuth well you need to consider the `LinearSearch` function.. How would you be able to compare `string`? Right now you are saying `"someString" > "searchString"` so it makes sense it might work with `int`